# LINQ to Sql Left Outer Join with Group By and Having Clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda

I lost a day to try translate a sql query to LINQ lambda expression but not success.

My sql query:

```
SELECT a.ID,
       Sum(b.[Value]) AS [Value],
       c.ContractValue
FROM   Contracts a
       LEFT JOIN DepositHistories b
              ON b.ContractID = a.ID
       INNER JOIN LearningPackages c
               ON a.LearningPackageID = c.ID
GROUP  BY a.ID,
          c.ContractValue
HAVING Sum(b.[Value]) < c.ContractValue
        OR Sum(b.[Value]) IS NULL
        OR Sum(b.[Value]) = 0
```

This is LINQ query:

```
var contracts = (
                from a in db.Contracts
                from b in db.LearningPackages.Where(e => e.ID == a.LearningPackageID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                group a by new
                {
                    a.ID,
                    b.ContractValue
                } into g
                from c in db.DepositHistories.Where(e => e.ContractID == g.Key.ID).DefaultIfEmpty()
                where g.Sum(e => c.Value) < g.Key.ContractValue || g.Sum(e => c.Value) == null
                select new
                {
                    ID = g.Key.ID,
                    ContractValue = g.Key.ContractValue,
                    Value = g.Sum(e => c.Value != null ? c.Value : 0)
                }
                ).ToList();
```

My result:

```
  ID  ContractValue    Value  
  1      6000000      500000  
  1      6000000      500000  
  1      6000000      500000  
  1      6000000      500000  
  1      6000000      500000  
  3      7000000      500000  
  3      7000000      500000  
  3      7000000      500000  
  4      6000000      500000  
  5      6000000      0  
  6      6000000      0
```

It's not group and sum the values.

Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried the whole day? Show your efforts.

Comment: We're not a code writing service. We help fix code that isn't working or is incomplete.

Comment: are you sure you dont want this INNER JOIN to be executed before your LEFT JOIN ????

Comment: @M.Ali: joins aren't necessarily executed in the order they are declared.

Comment: I just update my code, please help me!

Comment: Thanks for code. Could you please now tell us what means "but not success" ?

Comment: @MitchWheat but still it wouldn't make any sense to have a LEFT before INNER join since the inner join will filter out all the non-matching rows (unless it is intentional).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
var result = from b in db.DepositHistories
             join a in db.Contracts on b.CotractID equals a.ID
             join c in db.LearningPackages on a.LearningPackageID equals c.ID
             group b by new{ a.ID,c.COntractValue} into g
             where g.Sum(x=>x.Value) < g.Key.COntractValue 
             || g.Sum(x=>x.Value) == null 
             || g.Sum(x=>x.Value) == 0
            select new 
                  { 
                   ID = g.Key.ID, 
                   Value = g.Sum(x=>x.Value), 
                   ContractValue = g.Key.COntractValue
                  };
```

I made a [DEMO FIDDLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t0b1iH) to be more clear.

### UPDATE:

For left outer join you have to do `join your condition into somealias` and them `from alias in somealias.DefaultIfEmpty()`.

Here is the version with left outer join which gives correct results:

```
var result = from a in Contracts
             join b in DepositHistories on a.ID equals b.CotractID into e
             from f in e.DefaultIfEmpty()
             join c in LearningPackages on a.LearningPackageID equals c.ID
             group f by new 
                       { 
                          a.ID, 
                          c.COntractValue 
                       } into g
             where g.Sum(x => x==null ? 0 : x.Value) < g.Key.COntractValue 
             ||  g.Sum(x => x==null ? 0 : x.Value) == 0
             select new 
                   { 
                      ID = g.Key.ID, 
                      Value = g.Sum(x => x == null ? 0 : x.Value), 
                      ContractValue = g.Key.COntractValue 
                   };
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9TcC6w)

You can also check [this SO post about How to do left outer join in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142151/linq-to-sql-multiple-tables-outer-join)

### UPDATE 2:

Using query method you have to use [GroupJoin() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301847.aspx) for left outer join.

Here is the above code with Method Query:

```
var Result = Contracts.GroupJoin(DepositHistories, 
                                    a => a.ID, 
                                    b => b.CotractID, 
                                    (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b })
                                  .Join(LearningPackages, 
                                  a => a.a.LearningPackageID, 
                                  b => b.ID, 
                                  (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b })
                                  .GroupBy(e => new 
                                                    { 
                                                        e.a.a.ID, 
                                                        e.b.COntractValue 
                                                    }, 
                                                    (k, g) => new 
                                                                { 
                                                                    ID = k.ID, 
                                                                    ContractValue = k.COntractValue, 
                                                                    Value =  g.Sum(x => x == null ? 0 : x.a.b.Sum(d=>d.Value)) 
                                                                }
                                            ).Where(x => x.Value < x.ContractValue || x.Value == 0).ToList();
```

[UPDATED FIDDLE WITH METHOD QUERY](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wuhnYI)

Comment: Thanks for your code, but this code not get all my contracts, which have DepositHistories is null.

Comment: My sql query have left join, how to can I make this in LINQ query?

Comment: @SơnLê check the updated post with updated demo, it will now give accurate results now it is left outer join

Comment: the ``into e from f in e.DefaultIfEmpty()`` is doing left outer join

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I try convert this code to method query, you can edit to show beuty code:
Contracts
 .Join(DepositHistories, a => a.ID, b => b.ContractID, (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b })
 .Join(LearningPackages, a => a.a.LearningPackageID, b => b.ID, (a, b) => new { a = a, b = b })
 .GroupBy(e => new { e.a.a.ID, e.b.ContractValue }, (k, g) => new
 {
     ID = k.ID,
     ContractValue = k.ContractValue,
     Value = g.Sum(x => x == null ? 0 : x.a.b.Value)
 })
 .Where(x => x.Value < x.ContractValue || x.Value == 0)
 .ToList()

How to can I using DefaultIfEmpty() in this?
Thanks!

Comment: @Son Le In method query we have groupjoin method see the SO post whose link I added in my answer, currently I am on cell fone so cannot do much, will update my post from PC

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, Thanks for your code but yesterday I had make code like you, but this still don't show left join result, your code also.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, Seem you changed source code again after my above comment?