# how to use group by in linq C# and fetch the list of records

Tags: linq, sql-to-linq-conversion

i have a 2 tables and i do some joins to return a list of records based on some requirement.
I am able to write a group by query for my requiremnet and fecth the records,but i need the same in Linq query.
my sql query is :

```
select 
   MiscServiceDesc, 
   sum(PaymentAmount),
   count(PaymentAmount) 
from 
   MiscTransaction MT 
join MiscService MS 
   on MT.MiscServiceID = MS.MiscServiceID 
group by 
  MiscServiceDesc
```

where MiscTransaction and MiscService are my two tables.

Any help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i need when a join is there.

Comment: @Santosh It is written the same way, join or no join.

Comment: also check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730575/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-group-by-and-having-clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. I dont know MiscServiceDesc, PaymentAmount, PaymentAmount which of these columns are in MiscTransaction table or MiscService table, but you can change the code appropriatly if needed.

```
var result = (from mt in MiscTransaction 
               join ms in MiscService on mt.MiscServiceID equals ms.MiscServiceID
               select new {ms.MiscServiceDesc, mt.PaymentAmount} into lst
               group lst by lst.MiscServiceDesc into gr
               select new {MiscServiceDesc  = gr.Key, Summ = gr.Sum(c=>c.PaymentAmount), Count = gr.Count()}
       ).ToList();
```