# searching using linq

Tags: sql, linq

i am new to linq and having a hard time to implement searching using two table , i have  a sql server stored procedure that is working fine , but i want to do it with linq and its both are looking very different can not able to implement count of user and Contains Properly , can anyone help me on this
here is my sql to which i am trying to implement in linq

```
 @pTeamName Varchar (25) = 'ALL',
 @pUserFirstName Varchar (25) = 'ALL'
    select 
        t.TeamId,TeamName,[Description],
        COUNT(u.UserId)as UserCount from Team t
  left outer join  [User] u on u.TeamId=t.TeamId
  WHERE
    (t.TeamName Like '%'+@pTeamName+'%' OR @pTeamName Like 'ALL')
  AND (u.FirstName = @pUserFirstName OR @pUserFirstName Like 'ALL')
  AND t.Deleted = 0
  group by 
  TeamName,
  [Description],
  t.TeamId
```

and here is my linq what i have so far

```
from t in Teams
join u in Users on t.TeamId equals u.TeamId
where t.TeamName.Contains("Tester")
select new {t.TeamName,t.Description,u.UserId}
```

Comment: This may help out :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27730575/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join-with-group-by-and-having-clause

Comment: sir can you please give me an example

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this,

```
    var result = from t in Teams
    join u in Users on t.TeamId equals u.TeamId into j1
    where (t.TeamName.Contains("Tester") || t.TeamName.Contains("ALL") ) && (u.FirstName.Contains("username") || u.FirstName.Contains("ALL")) && t.Deleted = 0
    from j2 in j1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    Group j2 by new
     {
       t.TeamName,
       t.Description,
       t.TeamID,
      } into gcs
   select new {TeamName = gcs.key.TeamName,Description = gcs.Key.Description,Count = gcs.Count(x=>x.UserId)}
```

**Not tested may want to check for the syntax error**

Comment: Thanks for your Reply , yeah i am getting some syntax error

Comment: i am not familiar with, can you please help

Comment: Can you put some data and you expected output data in question so I can give you the exact expression.

Comment: Suppose User input for TeamName is "Te" then all teamname that contains te should be listed, or if user input "Tester" for Teamname and "Mark" as userName then output should be the particular record only which name is mark and team is Tester .