# left join linq - object reference is null

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

I have this query below which works fine in LINQPad but it's giving me an error in my project

```
var query = from c in corps
            join cl in corpsPlaces on c.CorpID equals cl.CorpID into cl_join
            from cl in cl_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join l in places on cl.PlaceID equals l.PlaceID into l_join
            from l in l_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
            {
             c.CorpID,
             Name =  l.PlaceName == null ? c.CorpName : (l.PlaceName + " - " + c.CropName)
            };
```

I know I am using left join and name can be null therefore I used that conditional operator and the error line

```
 join l in places on cl.PlaceID equals l.PlaceID into l_join
```

I'm using EF 6, if it matters.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: You need give us some background on your database so we can help you. And use grammar and spelling so people are more likely to answer. How to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example [mcve]

Comment: what part you didnt understand Grammatical Wise?

Comment: it's not a problem of understanding, but of quality. for example, you use "i" instead of "I". you also say "im using ef 6 if it matters" instead of "I'm using ef 6 if it matters". What's ef?

Comment: not to be a grammar nazi, just trying to get you more answers

Comment: ef is Entity Framework :D

Comment: We need you to get further in the problem-solving than just "I have a null reference". Please provide a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, as well as explain _specifically_ what is null, what you've done already to try to resolve the null reference, and what _specific_ difficulty you are still having in fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You get a null reference exception for the cl.PlaceID in the second left join right? The reason in that cl is null and so cl.PlaceID results in a NullReferenceException.

You should use GroupJoin to perform so. Please look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142151/linq-to-sql-multiple-tables-left-outer-join)