# C# - from SQL to Linq - Left Outer Join/Inner Join

Tags: c#, sql, linq, left-join, inner-join

I got this in SQL:

with 3 Values: value1, value2, value3

```
SELECT A.a, A.b, E.c, B.d, A.e, A.f, A.g, D.h, D.i 

FROM Alpha as A 

INNER JOIN Beta as B ON A.b = B.k 

LEFT OUTER JOIN Charlie as C ON C.a = A.a  

LEFT OUTER JOIN Delta as D ON D.k = B.j  

INNER JOIN Echo as E ON A.a = E.a     

WHERE A.a = @value1 AND E.c = @value2 AND (A.a = @value3 OR @value3 = '') AND A.b = E.b
```

Alpha, Beta, Charlie, Delta and Echo have string a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k.

I've tried to convert into Linq, but I don't get the Syntax of join right. Can you show me how it should look? x)

```
public static List<value> GetSmthn(string value1, string value2, string value3)
{           

    return (
         from A in Alpha

         join B in Beta on A.b equals B.k

         join C in Charlie on A.a equals C.a 

         join D in Delta on B.j equals D.k 

         join E in Echo on E.a equals A.a

         where (A.a == value1 && E.c == value2 && (A.a == value3 || value3 == "") && A.b == E.b)

         select new value() { a = A.a, b = A.b, c = E.c, d = A.d, e = A.e, f = A.f, g = A.g, h = D.h i = D.i }

         ).ToList();
}
```

Thanks for help, maybe it's a bit confusing. Cause I changed the variable-names.
Sorry for the bad english btw

Comment: You may want to check out [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) for Left Joins in linq.  Looks like you'll have to use a group join and use `DefaultIfEmpty`

Comment: you should check `DefaultIfEmpty` option with join.  Check below link for more information related to joins. 

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: That's the problem, i don't get it on MDSN.. I don't know why, i can't understand it so im asking for help :D

Comment: it is on MSDN, Check the link i have provided and go through the Left Outer Join section.

Comment: I know the Theory, but I don't know how to use it, in my Code..

Comment: Maybe take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17142392/6530134.  You are probably going to need to do it a few times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx):

> To perform a left outer join in LINQ, use the DefaultIfEmpty method in combination with a group join to specify a default right-side element to produce if a left-side element has no matches. You can use null as the default value for any reference type, or you can specify a user-defined default type.

From what I can tell, you first join all the data via a [GroupJoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301847.aspx)  This "correlates the elements of two sequences based on key equality and groups the results."  Then, the following `from` specifies a default right-side element (by using `DefaultIfEmpty()`) to produce if a left-side element has no matches.  You will need to perform this for all of your left joins:

```
public static List<value> GetSmthn(string value1, string value2, string value3)
    {           

    return (
         from A in Alpha

         join B in Beta on A.b equals B.k

         join C in Charlie on A.a equals C.a into cgroup
         from C in cgroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

         join D in Delta on B.j equals D.k into dgroup
         from D in dgroup.DefaultIfEmpty()

         join E in Echo on E.a equals A.a

         where (A.a == value1 && E.c == value2 && (A.a == value3 || value3 == "") && A.b == E.b)

         select new value() { a = A.a, b = A.b, c = E.c, d = A.d, e = A.e, f = A.f, g = A.g, h = D.h i = D.i }

         ).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: why is after charlie and delta a from, and after echo not?

Comment: ah ok I got it xD

Comment: on the Internet-Pages is always a "new Product { Name = String.Empty, CategoryID = 0 }" or something like that, inside of DefaultIsEmpty() why do do we not need it here?

Comment: @R.Lorch I was following what you've provided in your question. I also don't see the example you mention in my links.

Comment: "from item in prodGroup.DefaultIfEmpty(new Product { Name = String.Empty, CategoryID = 0 })" on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx

Comment: @R.Lorch Ah I see what you mean now.  If you read above: "You can use null as the default value for any reference type, **or you can specify a user-defined default type."**  What they are doing is specifying a user defined default type. It's optional.  In the code I have in my answer, I am using just `null`.

Comment: I think sometimes to read the texts is clever^^ thanks mate:D