# Linq GroupJoin (join...into) results in INNER JOIN?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I am referencing the accepted answer to this question:
[LINQ to SQL multiple tables left outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142151/linq-to-sql-multiple-tables-left-outer-join/17142392#17142392)

In my example, I need all of the Person records regardless if there is a matching Staff record.

I am using the following query (simplified for illustation's sake):

```
var result = from person in context.Person
                     join staffQ in context.Staff
                         on person.StaffID equals staffQ.ID into staffStaffIDGroup
                     from staff in staffStaffIDGroup.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new PersonModel()
                     {
                         ID = person.ID,
                         Fname = person.Fname,
                         Lname = person.Lname,
                         Sex = person.Sex,
                         Username = staff != null ? staff.Username : ""
                     };
```

However, contrary to my expectations, the query results in the following SQL with an INNER JOIN, which eliminates records I need in the the result set.

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
[Extent1].[fname] AS [fname], 
[Extent1].[lname] AS [lname], 
[Extent1].[sex] AS [sex], 
[Extent2].[username] AS [username]
FROM  [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Staff] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[StaffID] = [Extent2].[ID]
```

I thought that GroupJoin (or join...into) is supposed to get around this? I know I must have made a dumb mistake here, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the query should generate `left outer join`.

But remember, this is EF, and it has additional information coming from the model. In this case looks like the `StaffID` property of `Person` is an enforced FK constraint to `Stuff`, so EF knows that there is always a corresponding record in `Staff` table, hence ignoring your `left outer join` construct and generates `inner join` instead.

Again, the model (properties, whether they are required or not, the relationships - required or not etc.) allows EF to perform similar smart decisons and optimizations.

Comment: This was it. I ran into this a few years ago as well, and completely forgot.