# Outer Join on two List<> objects returned from entity framework query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have two Lists (`List<>`) that I want to perform outer join.

`revisionsByDate` looks like this:

```
DateCreated  RevisionCount
10-09-2019   15
11-09-2019   17
12-09-2019   5
13-09-2019   7
```

`progresUpdates` looks like this:

```
DateCreated  Progress
10-09-2019   60
13-09-2019   90
14-09-2019   100
```

I need to do an outer join on these `List` objects. I tried the following code, which works fine but does an `inner` join:

```
    var resultsToReturn = revisionsByDate.Join(
         progresUpdates,
         revision => revision.DateCreated,
         action => action.DateCreated,
         (revision, action) => new {
             revision.RevisionCount, action.Progress, action.DateCreated });
```

Output is:

```
DateCreated Progress  RevisionCount
10-09-2019  60        15
13-09-2019  90        7
14-09-2019  100       0
```

But, I want to achieve the following:

```
DateCreated  Progress  RevisionCount
10-09-2019   60        15
11-09-2019   60        17
12-09-2019   60        5
13-09-2019   100       7
14-09-2019   100       0
```

You may notice that the latest progress `60` is repeated if there is no matching value for the `DateCreated` value of the `revisionsByDate`.

Any ideas to convert my code to `outer` join? Also, I wonder if I should do this already in `sql`? I am using Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL multiple tables left outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142151/linq-to-sql-multiple-tables-left-outer-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is *both* a left and a right join, one after the other.

Try this:

```
var resultsLeft = revisionsByDate.Select(r => new
                                              {
                                                  Revision = r,
                                                  Action = progressUpdates.Where(pu => pu.DateCreated <= r.DateCreated)
                                                          .OrderByDescending(pu => pu.DateCreated)
                                                                          .First()
                                              })
                                 .Select(_ => new
                                             {
                                                 _.Revision.DateCreated,
                                                 _.Action.Progress,
                                                 _.Revision.RevisionCount
                                             })
                                 .ToList();

var resultsRight = progressUpdates.GroupJoin(revisionsByDate,
                                             pu => pu.DateCreated,
                                             r => r.DateCreated,
                                            (pu, rr) => new                                                                    
                                                        {                                                                        
                                                           ProgressUpdate = pu,                                                                          
                                                           NoMatch =  !rr.Any()                                                                            
                                                        })
                                  .Where(pu => pu.NoMatch)
                                  .Select(pu => new
                                                {
                                                    pu.ProgressUpdate.DateCreated,
                                                    pu.ProgressUpdate.Progress,
                                                    RevisionCount = 0
                                                })
                                  .ToList();


var results = resultsLeft.Concat(resultsRight)
                         .OrderBy(r => r.DateCreated)
                         .ToList();
```